# Creating staitic method and calling the method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, static

I'm getting value form Form class by creating object.It's working fine.But I wanna do it using static method.I tried but did not succeed.

```
public function display()
{
    $newform=new Form();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($newform->getAll());

    var_dump($newform->get('name'));
}

<?php 

class Form
{
    private $value = array();

    function __construct() {
        // here you can use some validation or escapes 
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
            $this->value[$key] = $value;

    }

    public function getAll() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function get($value) {
        $this->value = $_POST[$value];

        return $this->value;
    }

}
```

Comment: static method is defined by static keyword, `public static function foo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You should just try to read [PHP documentation about static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)?

Example:

```
class Form {

    private static $value = array();

    public static function factory() {
        // here you can use some validation or escapes 
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            static::$value[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public static function getAll() {
        return static::$value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        return static::$value[$key];
    }

}
```

Use:

```
public function display() {
    Form::factory();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(Form::getAll());
    var_dump(Form::get('name'));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for `getAll` method. For `get` method the same idea:

```
public function display()
{
    var_dump(Form::getAll());
}

class Form
{
    private static $value = array();
   public static function initPost()
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        self::$value[$key] = $value;
    }
    public static function getAll()
    {
        return self::$value;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's just giving me am empty string @sergio

Comment: Because you you didn't create object of `Form` class, and `__constructor` doesn't call, and $_POST didn't set to $value variable.

Comment: Why should I create the object of Form class when I'm calling static method?Can you please modify your answer.

Comment: @Navid Anjum. Edited. But you need to call Form::initPost() to set POST darta into array.

Answer (score 0):

you do not declare a function as public/private/protected outside of the class

you you want to call this method statically, you may try it

```
<?php
     function display()
{
    $newform=new Form($_POST);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(Form::getAll());

    var_dump(Form::get('name'));
}

class Form
{
private static $value = array();
function __construct(){
// here you can use some validation or escapes 
function __constract($array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        self::$value[$key] = $value;

    }
}
public static function getAll(){

    return self::$value;
}
public static function get($value){

        self::$value = self::$value[$value];

    return self::$value;
}

}
```